# jekyll correctly adding additional pages/broken links or css

Tags: jekyll

I'm using jykell to create a personal website. Check it out here [chrisCPO.com](http://chrisCPO.com) general feedback is welcome. Still a wip.

UPDATE: looks like some of the site root vars are not being rendered on added pages. Home link code is:

`<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}">`

which works but is being overridden on the additional page?

---

If you visit the site notice click on experience on the sidebar.Then try to go to the home page.

Issue is if I add a page like the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) say to I get all of my added pages in-site links are broken. They are rendering as

`<a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="">Home</a>`

instead of

`<a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="/">Home</a>`

notice the href.

note: both of these issues are on production only, everything works fine locally.

What is the correct way to add an additional page so everything works?

using jekyll 3.0

Comment: Question should contain the relevant source code to answer it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your CSS paths in your layout relative to the root of the site, like this: /css/style.css (notice the first slash). Then the choice for folders or no folders becomes irrelevant. Permalinks can be managed globally in the config file. See the docs.

Comment: Hi thanks,

So it looks link the css is now working, the paths were relative to the root. not sure what the issue was there. However links are still broken.